# Open applications with Python, doesn't work when there are spaces in app name

Tags: macos, python-3.x, os.system

I am trying to open applications using python. At the moment, this is what I have got:

```
os.system("open " + "/Applications/" + app + ".app")
```

('app' is a string with an appname, changes throughout the script)

Now, my problem is that this works flawlessly when I try to open apps with a single word for their name. Like "Blender" or "Brackets". However, if I try to open apps like photoshop (which in the applications folder are named "Adobe Photoshop CS6") nothing happens. I have been trying for several hours now, went through a lot of questions, many of them talking about adding an 'r' before the string. I have tried this before every part of my string, and also tried to encapsulate it all between quotes but nothing helps.

Why is this even an issue?

Comment: You're really executing a shell command. Guess what `open Adobe Photoshop CS6.app` means in the shell: 3 separate arguments. You need to quote/escape for shell syntax at the very least: `open 'Adobe Photoshop CS6.app'`.

Comment: Having said that, there's gotta be better ways to do this in Python than going through the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes around the `.app` bit:

```
os.system("open " + "'/Applications/" + app + ".app'")
                     ^                             ^
```

so it expands to:

```
open '/Application/Hello World.app'
```

You should probably be using [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) anyway, which accepts arguments in array elements and doesn't suffer from this issue.